# QTabWidget or QTabBar displaying the same QWidget in different tabs using C++

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I'm working with a QTabWidget right now displaying just one QWidget with different elements (labels, buttons, ...). Working with Ubuntu and Qt5.5.

```
QTabWidget *tw;
QString title = "1";
ui->tw->addTab(&tab, title); // tab is my QWidget
```

I'd like to show the same QWidget in more than one tab with different values. Is there a "clean" for it?

Micha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a "clean" way to do that. The `QTabWidget` uses a stack, so you will need to have separate widgets for each tab. It is said in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) :

> Each tab is associated with a different widget (called a page).

The only way is to instantiate several instances of `QWidget` and add them to your `QTabWidget`.

```
QTabWidget *tw;
QString title  = "1";
QString title2 = "2";
ui->tw->addTab(&tab, title);   // tab is your QWidget
ui->tw->addTab(&tab2, title2); // tab2 is another QWidget
```

If you want to use a `QTabBar`, just put your widget within it (using a `QVBoxLayout` for example). Then connect to the QTabBar's `currentChanged` signal to change your widget according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Too bad that I can't just insert the same widget several times.. Do you have any experiences regarding a QTabBar instead of QTabWidget?

Comment: Do you have an example you could share? I'm not completely sure how to simply work with the QTabBar.. :/

Comment: Did it! Thanks so much for your help. Couldn't think of an easier solution though. :)
Marked as solved!